# Keycloak load users

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I need to load all users from Keycloak and insert (cache) them into my system via keycloak-admin-client. While querying small number of users are pretty quick, the speed exponentially grows. Loading of 500 users takes 8 seconds, but 3000 users takes up to 4 minutes and I need to load 13k+. It seems like the methods search(search, first,max) and list(first,max) behaves same.

```
 kc.realm(realmName).users().list(0, count)
```

I thought that doing the loading by chunks (list(0,1000) then (list(1001,2000))) would solve the problem but it take exactly same time to load 0,2000 than 1001,2000, which seems like Keycloak is querying all the users from beginning and then doing substring.

The question is: how to do the bulk (chunk, iterative) load of all users from Keycloak to another system? I would like to avoid touching Keycloak DB directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the parameters are first and max, so in order to iterate over users I need to increase only the first number and let the second one remains same. So the request would looks like this with looping only parameter **first** by increasing it by 100

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/demorealm/users/?first=5500&max=100
```